# PHP says variables are undefined when they aren't

Tags: php

I'm working on a small framework for projects that I develop, but when I set up the testing index page to call the class, it says that the variables are undefined. My index looks like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('settings.php');
$base = $settings['basedir'];
require_once($base.'/framework.php');

$cframe = new cFrame($base, $settings);
```

and my framework.php looks like this:

```
class cFrame {  
    public function __construct($base, $settings){
        $this->baseDir = $base;
        $this->settings = $settings;
        require_once($this->baseDir.'/db.php'); 
        require_once($this->baseDir.'/layout.class.php');
        $this->layout = new layoutFinder($this->baseDir.'/layout');
        $this->db = new database;
        $this->dbc = $db->connectDB();

        echo $baseDir;
    }
}
```

The error messages that I get when trying to run this are:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for cFrame::__construct(), called in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 11 and defined in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 5
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for cFrame::__construct(), called in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 11 and defined in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: base in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: settings in
>   /var/www/cFrame/coreFrame/framework.php on line 7

Which is saying that the variables are not defined, but they are.

Comment: I doubt that is the real code leading to those errors. The error messages do not fit.

Comment: Something else is happening here.

Comment: @arkascha Well, that's all the relevant code. My database file doesn't even end up being included since those variables are apparently undefined.

Comment: @Steve_B19 Could you elaborate? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: is the $settings variable set in settings.php ?

Comment: @Billy Yes, and the base variable works for including the framework file.

Comment: what happens when you declare the variables as null before assigning them?

Comment: $base == $settings and $settings ==$base ?? I mean, where is settings defined?

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon settings is defined in the settings file.

Comment: @Steve_B19 The same thing happens.

Comment: @Core what php version are you using?

Comment: show the contents of `settings.php`

Comment: @Core can you var_dump($base) and paste contents

Comment: @Steve_B19 Actually, I just realized that this has to do with calling the DB class, which is a child to he cFrame class, inside the cFrame constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `db` was a child class of `cFrame`, which means that I wouldn't have been able to call it from inside the parent class like I was trying to.

Comment: To reiterate - there is no such thing as  a private / protected or nested class or function in PHP. Even if you `include` them inside class definitions. PHP just declares them globally.